# Writing to new row - Xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter, stock

First time posting be gentle as I'm currently learning Python on the fly at work. :)

Anywho, I decided to try and write something that will print a stock price every 2 minutes to Excel, using xlsxwriter and Selenium to get the webpage.

My issue here is, that when it writes to excel only the first Rows are populated. When the 2 minutes are up, the new price (if there is one) wont write to excel on a new line.

Any help is gratefully appreciated of course - Really looking forward to being part of the community! :)

Cheers guys!

Code is:

```
times = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r'\\dub-ppfs-001\Home\rglennon\Desktop\Firefox_Web_driver\Stock_Price.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
col = 1
row = 0


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/pypl')

WebDriverWait(browser, 60, 5).until(ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="value"]')))
browser.minimize_window()
pypl = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="value"]')
openprice = (browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="intraday__close"]').text)


while True:
    for row in range(1):
        sheet.write(row, 0, pypl.text)
        row =+1
    for col in range(1):
        sheet.write(col, 1, times)
         col =+1
    if pypl.text >= '105.50':
        ps('metal.mp3')



    workbook.close()
    time.sleep(120)
```

Comment: Please note that this script will not get the newest stockprice every two minutes, but will only write the same data every two minutes, you will need to reload the page and assign `pypl` inside the `while` loop. Also, you don't need the two for loops `for row in range(1):` since they don't achieve anything in this case. And although you named the variable `col` you use its value as the row argument in the `.write` method.

Comment: And as a suggestion, using `urllib` and `requests` modules might be better suited for your use case, since you don't actually need to open a browser to achieve what you're trying to do =)

Comment: The main reason for why nothing's happening after the first iteration is because you `.close` the workbook at the end of the loop but never open it again. You would actually want to close the workbook after the loop is finished (which will not work in this case, since you're missing a `try - except` statement to leave the endless `while True` loop).

Comment: Hey m.schalk! Thanks for all the assistance so far! When I get a chance I'll reopen the script and try the try-except statements. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with the help above! Thank you kindly :)

just had to alter the loop really:

```
try:

pypl = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="value"]')
openprice = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="intraday__close"]').text




while True:
    pypl = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="value"]')
    times = strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    sheet.write(row, 0,   pypl.text)
    row =row+1
    sheet.write(col, 1,   times)
    col =col+1

    print('PayPals current price is: $' +pypl.text)
    print('recorded at the time of : ' +times)
    print('\n')
    time.sleep(10)

    browser.refresh()
    WebDriverWait(browser, 60, 5).until(ec.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="value"]')))
    pypl = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="value"]')

except KeyboardInterrupt:
sheet.write_formula('D1', '=MAXA(A:A)')
workbook.close()


browser.quit()
```